# Create a deeply nested field array form using react hook form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I want to collect my data in this format from the user. there are some general values at the top level then there is a detail field that can be multiple means it is an array and user can add multiple details. Now every single detail has some general values but also values that are array themselves means every they can be multiple also. How can I achieve that here is the sample output that I am looking for. I am thinking of using react-hook-forms but it gets messy pretty quick.

````
    "images": "Add images here using formdata",
    "video": "Video URL only",
    "fee": 999,
    "duration": 999,
    "active": true,
    "mode": "Online",
    "details": [
        {
            "language": "6517f3cadfb3719cb7d095b9",
            "title": "Computer Science",
            "description": "BSCS",
            "instructorTitle": "Science Teacher",
            "instructorName": "Umair",
            "duration": "5 Months",
            "features":[
                "dssd",
                "asdasd"
            ],
            "faqs":[
                {
                    "question":"Hey",
                    "answer":"Hello"
                }   
            ]
        },
        {
            "language": "6517f3d3dfb3719cb7d095c1",
            "title": "Computer Science",
            "description": "BSCS",
            "instructorTitle": "Science Teacher",
            "instructorName": "Umair",
            "duration": "5 Months",
            "features":[
                "dssd",
                "asdasd"
            ],
            "faqs":[
                {
                    "question":"Hey",
                    "answer":"Hello"
                }   
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````